# Visualizing and clustering user activity within tool ecosystem

Tags: time-series, clustering, data-visualization

I have a large amount of telemetry for a population of users using a tool suite. In many cases, users are working on a number of different tasks over the course of a day, and hopping back and forth between tools constantly. The data mostly looks like `<timestamp, userid, tool, complex json blob describing what they did>`

By visual inspection, I can see that there are "clusters" of users that only use a certain set of tools, and use them a particular way (i.e. they hop back and forth between two tools dozens of times an hour. I am familiar with clustering algorithms (knn, dbscan, etc) but I have no idea how to put this kind of time series data into any of those.

Two questions:

1. Is there a good set of visualizations for depicting this kind of activity of hoping between states/tools where the number of hops is important? I am currently using https://timelinestoryteller.com/ in Power BI, but I can't really show more than one person at a time, it just gets insanely busy and intelligable
2. Is there a good reference for doing this kind of analysis? Ideally some kind of statistic that can capture "number of tight loops between states/tools". Even just a pointer to what this analysis is called would be helpful